# $g(z) = \int_{0}^{2\pi}f(e^{i\theta})\frac{e^{-i\theta}}{e^{-i\theta}-\bar{z}}d\theta$ is antiholomorphic

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I 've encountered this fact: if $z \in D(0,1) $ and $f$ is continous on $\partial D(0,1) $ then $$g(z) = \int_{0}^{2\pi}f(e^{i\theta})\frac{e^{-i\theta}}{e^{-i\theta}-\bar{z}}d\theta$$ is antiholomorphic. Why is it true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $g(\overline{z})$ is holomorphic? What do you know about integrals like the used in the definition of $g(z)$?